# Using VBA If then statement to copy and paste data

Tags: vba, excel

I am a brand new VBA user attempting to copy and paste data based on a range of dates. In column one I have dates and in column two I have the data I would like to copy and paste. CurYear refers to the end date in the range I am looking for and StatDate refers to the beginning date in the Range I am looking for. When I run this code it crashes Excel. Please help I am very lost

```
Worksheets("Weekly").Select

Dim nRows As Integer
Dim CurYear As Date
Dim StartDate As Date

nRows=Range("A1").CurrentRegions.Count.Rows
CurYear=Range("I265").Value
StartDate=Range("M5").Value

Do While Cells(nRows,1)<>""

if Cells(nRows,1).Value< CurYear & Cells(nRows,1)> StartDate Then

Cells(nRows,1).Offset(0,1).Copy
Worksheets("Weekly").Range("H41").Paste

Loop
End If
```

Comment: I would just let Cells(nRows,1).Offset(0,1).value = Worksheets("Weekly").Range("H41").value, no need to copy and paste

Comment: Also, the end if should be before the loop, I am getting an error with the currentregions.count.rows. I would probably create a proper range by setting a variable to A1 and another to the last used cell (Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address)

Comment: Press F8 in the debugger, what line is crashing?

Comment: Lowpar I am a little confused on how you would call on the cell range within the do while loop. This is what I have, how should I fill in blank

CurYear = Range("I265").Value
StartDate = Range("M5").Value
x = Range("A1")
y = Range("A1").End(xlDown)

Do While Cells _____ <> ""

Comment: Lowpar, the debugger is not telling me any line in specific is crashing. But, when I run the code to completion (F5) Excel crashes.

Comment: You are missing `nrows = nrows + 1`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Or possibly `nRows = nRows - 1`? (It's a bit hard to tell from `nRows=Range("A1").CurrentRegions.Count.Rows`, but if it is meant to be `nRows=Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` then nRows is starting at the end, so will need to work downward.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using copy/ paste that uses a lot of memory and makes the program run slow, you maybe want to consider the following code that serves the same purpose as your code or Rodger's yet faster than using `Select` and copy/ paste syntax.

```
Sub Test()
Dim nRows As Long, LastRow As Long   'Declare as Long instead of Integer to avoid overflow
Dim CurYear As Date, StartDate As Date

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Count the last used row in column 1 where you put the first data (dates)
nRows = 2    'Set the starting point of row where you put the first data (dates). In this example I use 2
CurYear = Range("I265").Value
StartDate = Range("M5").Value

Do
    If Cells(nRows, 1).Value < CurYear And Cells(nRows, 1) > StartDate Then 'Use And not &
        Cells(nRows, 5).Value = Cells(nRows, 2).Value   'This is essentially a "copy/ paste" syntax. Change the value (5) to the column you want to paste the value in column 2
    End If
    nRows = nRows + 1   'Set an increment value so each looping the nRows will increase by 1
Loop Until nRows = LastRow + 1   'Added by 1 so that the data in LastRow will keep being processed

End Sub
```

Comment: This is AWESOME! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put "option explicit" at the top of your code (before the sub) and it will tell you things to fix. Doing that will fix the part of your error where your end if was outside the loop instead of inside it but it won't catch that you weren't changing your loop counter. Try this code instead. It is actually pretty much the same as what you had with a couple minor changes.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim sht As Worksheet, i As Long, l As Long, j

Dim nRows As Integer
Dim CurYear As Date
Dim StartDate As Date

Set sht = Worksheets("Test1") ' set the sheet as object isntead of selecting it for faster code and avoiding other issues

nRows = Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'Last used row in column B - current region lastrow gets twitchy in some circumstances and should be avoided unless there is a reason to use it
l = 41

CurYear = range("I265").Value
StartDate = range("M5").Value

For i = 1 To nRows
  If Cells(i, 1).Value < CurYear And Cells(i, 1).Value > StartDate Then 'for If statements you use "and" not "&"
  Cells(l, 15) = Cells(i, 2) 'you will want something like this line and the next if you don't want to overwrite H41 if there is more than one match
  l = l + 1
  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Also, to help with debugging, Open your locals window (View in the VBE). Step through your code with F8, watching your variables in the locals window to ensure that they are what you expect them to be at that step in your script.

If you do this with your code, you will see that you were missing a counter change with your variable for your loop. So it was looking for nRow to eventually be "" but it stays at whatever it was set to. Infinite loop. I changed it to a for next format but 6 of 1 and half dozen of another for your code.

Welcome to VBA. Don't poke yer eye out. :-)

Comment: FYI - if you have trouble with other parts of the code and can't sort it with F8 stepping through and watching your locals window, be sure to search for new answers and start a new question if appropriate.

Comment: Rodger,
I am still having a bit of trouble with it. I am no longer crashing excel which, is awesome! but, the code above is not copying and pasting the values over. After I run the code "H41" remains blank.  I thought that it could potentially be an error with my dates however all of my dates are entered correctly.  PS I did not change anything on the code above except for which sheet it referred too

Comment: I edited the code above and added comments. Give it a shot. Oh, the cells (l,15) line will need to change the 15 to 8 if you want column H instead of Column O. I missed changing that back. And don't forget to hit the "accept answer" by the up down arrows if this takes care of you please. :)

Comment: Thank you! In this short time I have learned a butt ton about vba and how to use it. Thank you!